# How to respond data with an array instead of object

Tags: laravel

> I want to receive an array for data, something like this:

```
    "data": [
    "6": {
        "title": "..",
        "photo": ..
    }
]
```

> But I am receving an object :

```
    "data": {
    "6": {
        "title": "..",
        "photo": ".."
    }
}
```

> And another intresting fact is that for first page I am receiving how it is needed:

```
        "data": [
    "1": {
        "title": "..",
        "photo": ..
    },
.
.
.
        "6": {
            "title": "..",
            "photo": ..
        }
]
```

> This is my function in controller:

```
        $lists = [];
    $cooks = cook::all();
    foreach ($cooks as $cook) {
        $list = [
            'title' => $cook->title,
            'photo' => $cook->photos->path,
            'recipe' => $cook->recipe->description
        ];
        $lists[] = $list;
    }
    $collection = $this->paginate($lists, $perPage = 6, $page = null, $options = []);
    return new mainCollection($collection);
```

> I have the following function for pagination:

```
    public function paginate($items, $perPage = 15, $page = null, $options = [])
{
    $page = $page ?: (Paginator::resolveCurrentPage() ?: 1);
    $items = $items instanceof Collection ? $items : Collection::make($items);
    return new LengthAwarePaginator($items->forPage($page, $perPage), $items->count(), $perPage, $page, $options);
}
```

> and the following is my resourceColection(mainColection) :

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'data' => $this->collection,
        'meta' => ['pagination' => $this->pagination]
    ];
}
```

Comment: What is `mainCollection` doing?

Comment: is a resourceColection that I posted, It shows data and meta
should I post full mainColection?

Comment: Heave you tried `'data' => $this->collection->toArray()`?

Comment: Yes, didn't help, I am receiving the same thing

Comment: The first page I receive how it is needed  `"data": [
        {
            "title": "Tort",
            "photo": "",
            "recipe": ""
        },
    ],`

Comment: From the docs: [The framework will automatically convert the array into a JSON response](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#creating-responses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use laravel map since you're working with collections.

```
$array =  $this->collection->map(function ($item, $key) {
    return [
       'title': "tort",
        ...
    ]
});
```

and encode it as json

```
 public function toArray($request)
   {
    return [
        'data' => json_encode($array),
        'meta' => ['pagination' => $this->pagination]
    ];
   }
```

also you read the documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections